# Average of quad tree values

Tags: data-structures, tree

I have a question: A quadtree is defined in terms of primitive constructors baseQT(value) which returns a single node quad-tree with label value and makeQT(luqt,ruqt,llqt,rlqt) which builds a quad-tree from four constituent quad-
trees luqt; llqt; ruqt; rlqt, selectors lu(qt), ll(qt), ru(qt) and rl(qt), and condition isValue(qt) which returns true if quad-tree qt is a single node. Write a pseudo code averagevalue(qt), that uses the above primitive quadtree operators,
to return the average value of all nodes of quad tree.

So if I have a quadtree defined as makeQT(0,10,20,30) it should return 15 as 60/4 is 15.

What I have done so far is this, but I am not sure how to use recursion to get to every node of quad tree to use it in calculation of the average. Can anyone help me how to write a code after else statement?

```
  Int acc=0, int nodes=0;

 averagevalue(qt,acc,nodes) {

    if ( isValue(qt) )

        return ((qt)+acc)/(nodes+1)

     else

  }
```

Comment: You need to show more code, e.g. how the quad-tree structure is defined. Since Quadtrees are a recursive data structure, you must incorporate recursion in your code in some form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a recursive function that sums and counts the values, *then* computes the average. You probably need to write a helper function for that. For example:

```
// global variables
sum
count

averageValue(qt)
{
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    sumAndCount(qt);
    return sum/count;
}

sumAndCount(qt)
{
    if (qt != null)
    {
        sumAndCount(qt->luqt);
        sumAndCount(qt->ruqt);
        sumAndCount(qt->llqt);
        sumAndCount(qt->rlqt);
        sum += qt->value
        ++count
    }
}
```

Comment: @Augustas: See my corrected code. If you find this answer helpful, please upvote it and mark as the accepted answer.

Comment: I think that your corrected code is wrong now. Am I wrong?  I think that it is impossible to get to sum and count++ lines.

Comment: Actually, can it get even to the line sumAndCount(qt->ruqt)?

Comment: @Augustas: The corrected code *is* correct. It's a standard recursive depth-first tree traversal. Each node is followed to its leaves, and the `count` and `sum` are modified as the recursion unwinds. If it makes you feel better, you can modify the `sum` and `count` before the recursive calls: makes no difference. Either way, you want to do that inside the `if`, because otherwise you'd get an error trying to access the `value` field of a null reference.

Comment: The thing with what I am struggling is that for example you have a quadtree as qt=(10,0,20,30) where lu is 10, ru is 0 , ll is 20 and rl is 30.
I go to SumAndCount(qt). It is not null so I call sumAndCount(lu),  lu=10 is not equal to null so now the code goes back to sumAndCount(lu) and now I do not see how the code works because 10 was the leaf. Could you explain step by step how with this particular tree and your code get the answer of 15?

Comment: @Augustas: When it calls `SumAndCount(lu)` when the node is a leaf, `lu` is `null`. So the call returns immediately. Then it calls `SumAndCount(ru)`, which is also null. That continues for `ll` and `rl`, and then the `sum` and `count` are updated. If you want a more detailed explanation, leave another comment and I'll reply after I get some sleep.

Comment: I understand this code once I modify sum and count before recursive calls. However, when it is after recursive calls, I do not understand it. Thanks!